# Level out FFT graph (Processing)

Tags: java, processing, fft, visualization

I am trying to make a music visualizer in Processing, not that that part is super important, and I'm using a fast fourier transform through Minim. It's working perfectly (reading the data), but there is a large spike on the left (bass) end. What's the best way to 'level' this out?
My source code is [here](https://gist.github.com/thislooksfun/7191083428dab2de6799), if you want to take a look.

[image]

Thanks in advance,
-tlf

Comment: This is probably due to a DC offset in your signal.  Try subtracting the average of your signal while still in the time-domain (ie, take the original part of the waveform that you plan to fft but before you do the fft, add up all the values, divide by N, and subtract this value from each point in the waveform... then do the FFT).

Comment: Um. What? I'm sorry, but I have no idea what that means. XD
I have also edited my question to include my code, if that helps.

Comment: Look at your data closely and if the large spike is only at the very end (ie, zero frequency), just ignore it (eg, set it to zero).  This point corresponds to the average value of your data, which probably isn't what you are after in the plot.  It's a consequence of the mathematical definition of the FFT, but only rarely do people really care about it.

Comment: Basically, I have something that looks like [this](http://cl.ly/ZV1s), and I'm trying to make it look like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-QKYqhn9Q6g). I can just ignore that first stuff?

Comment: Nope.  I thought it was only the first point.  I'll try to write an answer with more details later, but have to quit now.  Meanwhile I've put your plot in your question (since I guess you can't with low rep), but it's very informative so please write a little explanatory text around it.

Comment: I *think* that the problem is just that the bass is louder than the treble, so that part of the graph is higher. I found that taking a smaller sample helps even it out a bit, but I still have a bit of testing to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out what I had to do was multiply the data by
`Math.log(i + 2) / 3`
where `i` is the index of the data being referenced, zero-indexed from the left (bass).
You can see this in context [here](https://github.com/thislooksfun/SoundReader/blob/master/src/net/tlf/soundreader/main/SoundReader.java#L191-L197)

Answer (score 0):

The spectrum you show looks fairly typical of a complex musical sound where you have a complex section at lower frequencies, but also some clear harmonics emerging from the low frequency mess.  And, actually, these harmonics are atypically clear... music in general is complicated.  Sometimes, for example, if a flute is playing a single clear note one will get a single nice peak or two, but it's much more common that transients and percussive sounds lead to a very complicated spectrum, especially at low frequencies.

For comparing directly to the video, it seems to me that the video is a bit odd.  My guess is that the spectrum they show is either a zoom in a small section of the spectrum far from zero, or that it's just a graphical algorithm that's based off the music but doesn't correspond to an actual spectrum.  That is, if you really want something to look very similar to this video, you'll need more than the spectrum, though the spectrum will likely be a good starting point.  Here are a few points to note:
1) there is a prominent peak which occasionally appears right above the "N" in the word anchor.  A single dominant peak should be clear in the audio as an approximately pure tone.
2) occasionally there's another peak that varies temporally with this peak, which would normally be a sign that the second peak is a harmonic, but many times this second peak isn't there.
3) A good examples of odd behavior, is a 2:26.  This time just follows a little laser sound effect, and then there's basically a quite hiss.  A hiss should be a broad spectrum sound without peaks, often weighted to lower frequencies.  At 2:26, though, there's just this single large peak above the "N" with nothing else.

Comment: Interesting... Well, thanks for that. I thought something was a bit off too, but I don't know enough about how these things really work to tell for sure. Marking this as the answer for saying it's not actually a spectrum.

Comment: It would be an interesting problem to figure out what they actually did here. Another option that occurs to me is that they: 1) flipped the spectrum so lower frequencies are on the right, and, more interstingly, 2) scaled the amplitudes so higher frequencies got a more weight (eg, multiplied the FFT amplitudes by `f`, or maybe something that flattens out at large f like a tweaked `log(f)` or sigmoidal)?

Comment: I tried doing a log, but I couldn't get it to work. I might try again though, because it really seems like it should.

Comment: I figured out the log! (Closely enough, anyway) :D